# Why is the top-left pixel of state image 1 in my DrawThemeBackground-based list view state image list clear on Windows XP?

Tags: c, listview, winapi, imagelist

I'm using state images to fake having checkboxes in every column of a standard list view control, and I've come across one weird anomaly on Windows XP that I'm not understanding: the top-left pixel of state image 1 is white, regardless of what that image actually is.

[Here's a (zoomed in) example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NZPR.jpg) You'll notice that the top-left pixel of the first image is blank.

It does not matter which state I draw for the first state image (change the first element of the `themestates` array in the same program below to see for yourself); all that seems to matter is that this only happens to state image 1 (index 0 in the HIMAGELIST).

IIRC this doesn't happen unthemed, and IIRC it doesn't happen on Windows 7.

The sample program below demonstrates this behavior (so I know it's not me accidentally overwriting memory in another part of my library, at least???).

What's going on? Thanks.

```
// 27 august 2014
// modified from winstateimglist.c 17 august 2014
// scratch Windows program by pietro gagliardi 17 april 2014
// fixed typos and added toWideString() 1 may 2014
// borrows code from the scratch GTK+ program (16-17 april 2014) and from code written 31 march 2014 and 11-12 april 2014
#define _UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#define STRICT
#define _GNU_SOURCE     // needed to declare asprintf()/vasprintf()
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>       // needed for InitCommonControlsEx() (thanks Xeek in irc.freenode.net/#winapi for confirming)
#include <uxtheme.h>
#include <vsstyle.h>
#include <vssym32.h>

#ifdef  _MSC_VER
#error sorry! the scratch windows program relies on mingw-only functionality! (specifically: asprintf())
#endif

HMODULE hInstance;
HICON hDefaultIcon;
HCURSOR hDefaultCursor;
HFONT controlfont;

void panic(char *fmt, ...);
TCHAR *toWideString(char *what);
void init(void);

LRESULT CALLBACK wndproc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    NMHDR *nmhdr = (NMHDR *) lparam;
    NMLVDISPINFOW *fill = (NMLVDISPINFO *) lparam;

    switch (msg) {
    case WM_NOTIFY:
        if (nmhdr->code == LVN_GETDISPINFO) {
            if (fill->item.iSubItem == 0) {
                fill->item.state = INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(fill->item.iItem + 1);
                fill->item.stateMask = LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;
            } else
                fill->item.pszText = L"No State Image Here";
            return 0;
        }
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
    }
    panic("oops: message %ud does not return anything; bug in wndproc()", msg);
}

HWND makeMainWindow(void)
{
    WNDCLASS cls;
    HWND hwnd;

    ZeroMemory(&cls, sizeof (WNDCLASS));
    cls.lpszClassName = L"mainwin";
    cls.lpfnWndProc = wndproc;
    cls.hInstance = hInstance;
    cls.hIcon = hDefaultIcon;
    cls.hCursor = hDefaultCursor;
    cls.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
    if (RegisterClass(&cls) == 0)
        panic("error registering window class");
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0,
        L"mainwin", L"Main Window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        300, 300,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (hwnd == NULL)
        panic("opening main window failed");
    return hwnd;
}

void buildUI(HWND mainwin)
{
#define CSTYLE (WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE)
#define CXSTYLE (0)
#define SETFONT(hwnd) SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM) controlfont, (LPARAM) TRUE);

    HWND lv;
    LVCOLUMN column;
    HIMAGELIST imglist;

    lv = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE | CXSTYLE,
        WC_LISTVIEW, L"",
        LVS_REPORT | LVS_OWNERDATA | LVS_NOSORTHEADER | LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP | CSTYLE,
        10, 10, 250, 250,
        mainwin, (HMENU) 100, hInstance, NULL);
    if (lv == NULL)
        panic("error making list view");
    SETFONT(lv);
    SendMessageW(lv, LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE,
        LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_SUBITEMIMAGES,
        LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_SUBITEMIMAGES);

    // error checking elided from this point to where otherwise noted

    HTHEME theme = NULL;
    HIMAGELIST makeCheckboxImageList(HWND hwnddc, HTHEME *theme);

    SendMessageW(lv, LVM_SETIMAGELIST, LVSIL_STATE, (LPARAM) makeCheckboxImageList(lv, &theme));

    ZeroMemory(&column, sizeof (LVCOLUMN));
    column.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM | LVCF_ORDER;
    column.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
    column.pszText = L"State Image";
    column.iSubItem = 0;
    column.iOrder = 0;
    SendMessageW(lv, LVM_INSERTCOLUMN, 0, (LPARAM) (&column));
    ZeroMemory(&column, sizeof (LVCOLUMN));
    column.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM | LVCF_ORDER;
    column.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
    column.pszText = L"No State Image";
    column.iSubItem = 1;
    column.iOrder = 1;
    SendMessageW(lv, LVM_INSERTCOLUMN, 1, (LPARAM) (&column));

    // end of error eliding

        if (SendMessageW(lv, LVM_SETCALLBACKMASK, LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK, 0) == FALSE)
        panic("error marking state image list as application-managed");
    if (SendMessageW(lv, LVM_SETITEMCOUNT, 8, 0) == 0)
        panic("error setting number of items in list view");
}

void firstShowWindow(HWND hwnd);

int main(void)
{
    HWND mainwin;
    MSG msg;

    init();

    mainwin = makeMainWindow();
    buildUI(mainwin);
    firstShowWindow(mainwin);

    for (;;) {
        BOOL gmret;

        gmret = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);
        if (gmret == -1)
            panic("error getting message");
        if (gmret == 0)
            break;
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}

DWORD iccFlags =
//  ICC_ANIMATE_CLASS |         // animation control
//  ICC_BAR_CLASSES |               // toolbar, statusbar, trackbar, tooltip
//  ICC_COOL_CLASSES |          // rebar
//  ICC_DATE_CLASSES |          // date and time picker
//  ICC_HOTKEY_CLASS |          // hot key
//  ICC_INTERNET_CLASSES |      // IP address entry field
//  ICC_LINK_CLASS |                // hyperlink
    ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES |          // list-view, header
//  ICC_NATIVEFNTCTL_CLASS |        // native font
//  ICC_PAGESCROLLER_CLASS |        // pager
//  ICC_PROGRESS_CLASS |            // progress bar
//  ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES |      // "one of the intrinsic User32 control classes"
//  ICC_TAB_CLASSES |               // tab, tooltip
//  ICC_TREEVIEW_CLASSES |      // tree-view, tooltip
//  ICC_UPDOWN_CLASS |          // up-down
//  ICC_USEREX_CLASSES |            // ComboBoxEx
//  ICC_WIN95_CLASSES |         // some of the above
    0;

void init(void)
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icc;
    NONCLIENTMETRICS ncm;

    hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    if (hInstance == NULL)
        panic("error getting hInstance");
    hDefaultIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));
    if (hDefaultIcon == NULL)
        panic("error getting default window class icon");
    hDefaultCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_ARROW));
    if (hDefaultCursor == NULL)
        panic("error getting default window cursor");
    icc.dwSize = sizeof (INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icc.dwICC = iccFlags;
    if (InitCommonControlsEx(&icc) == FALSE)
        panic("error initializing Common Controls");
    ncm.cbSize = sizeof (NONCLIENTMETRICS);
    if (SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS,
        sizeof (NONCLIENTMETRICS), &ncm, 0) == 0)
        panic("error getting non-client metrics for getting control font");
    controlfont = CreateFontIndirect(&ncm.lfMessageFont);
    if (controlfont == NULL)
        panic("error getting control font");
}

void panic(char *fmt, ...)
{
    char *msg;
    TCHAR *lerrmsg;
    char *fullmsg;
    va_list arg;
    DWORD lasterr;
    DWORD lerrsuccess;

    lasterr = GetLastError();
    va_start(arg, fmt);
    if (vasprintf(&msg, fmt, arg) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "critical error: vasprintf() failed in panic() preparing panic message; fmt = \"%s\"\n", fmt);
        abort();
    }
    // according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    lerrsuccess = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, lasterr,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lerrmsg, 0, NULL);
    if (lerrsuccess == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "critical error: FormatMessage() failed in panic() preparing GetLastError() string; panic message = \"%s\", last error in panic(): %ld, last error from FormatMessage(): %ld\n", msg, lasterr, GetLastError());
        abort();
    }
    // note to self: use %ws instead of %S (thanks jon_y in irc.oftc.net/#mingw-w64)
    if (asprintf(&fullmsg, "panic: %s\nlast error: %ws\n", msg, lerrmsg) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "critical error: asprintf() failed in panic() preparing full report; panic message = \"%s\", last error message: \"%ws\"\n", msg, lerrmsg);
        abort();
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", fullmsg);
    va_end(arg);
    exit(1);
}

void firstShowWindow(HWND hwnd)
{
    // we need to get nCmdShow
    int nCmdShow;
    STARTUPINFO si;

    nCmdShow = SW_SHOWDEFAULT;
    GetStartupInfo(&si);
    if ((si.dwFlags & STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW) != 0)
        nCmdShow = si.wShowWindow;
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    if (UpdateWindow(hwnd) == 0)
        panic("UpdateWindow(hwnd) failed in first show");
}

TCHAR *toWideString(char *what)
{
    TCHAR *buf;
    int n;
    size_t len;

    len = strlen(what);
    if (len == 0) {
        buf = (TCHAR *) malloc(sizeof (TCHAR));
        if (buf == NULL)
            goto mallocfail;
        buf[0] = L'\0';
    } else {
        n = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, what, -1, NULL, 0);
        if (n == 0)
            panic("error getting number of bytes to convert \"%s\" to UTF-16", what);
        buf = (TCHAR *) malloc((n + 1) * sizeof (TCHAR));
        if (buf == NULL)
            goto mallocfail;
        if (MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, what, -1, buf, n) == 0)
            panic("erorr converting \"%s\" to UTF-16", what);
    }
    return buf;
mallocfail:
    panic("error allocating memory for UTF-16 version of \"%s\"", what);
}

#define checkboxnStates 8

static int themestates[checkboxnStates] = {
    CBS_UNCHECKEDNORMAL,            // 0
    CBS_CHECKEDNORMAL,              // checked
    CBS_UNCHECKEDHOT,               // hot
    CBS_CHECKEDHOT,                 // checked | hot
    CBS_UNCHECKEDPRESSED,           // pushed
    CBS_CHECKEDPRESSED,             // checked | pushed
    CBS_UNCHECKEDPRESSED,           // hot | pushed
    CBS_CHECKEDPRESSED,             // checked | hot | pushed
};

static SIZE getStateSize(HDC dc, int cbState, HTHEME theme)
{
    SIZE s;
    HRESULT res;

    res = GetThemePartSize(theme, dc, BP_CHECKBOX, themestates[cbState], NULL, TS_DRAW, &s);
    if (res != S_OK)
        panic("error getting theme part size; HRESULT: %x", res);
    return s;
}

static void themeImage(HDC dc, RECT *r, int cbState, HTHEME theme)
{
    HRESULT res;

    res = DrawThemeBackground(theme, dc, BP_CHECKBOX, themestates[cbState], r, NULL);
    if (res != S_OK)
        panic("error drawing checkbox image; HRESULT: %x", res);
}

static void themeSize(HDC dc, int *width, int *height, HTHEME theme)
{
    SIZE size;
    int cbState;

    size = getStateSize(dc, 0, theme);
    for (cbState = 1; cbState < checkboxnStates; cbState++) {
        SIZE against;

        against = getStateSize(dc, cbState, theme);
        if (size.cx != against.cx || size.cy != against.cy)
            panic("size mismatch in checkbox states");
    }
    *width = (int) size.cx;
    *height = (int) size.cy;
}

static HBITMAP makeCheckboxImageListEntry(HDC dc, int width, int height, int cbState, void (*drawfunc)(HDC, RECT *, int, HTHEME), HTHEME theme)
{
    BITMAPINFO bi;
    VOID *ppvBits;
    HBITMAP bitmap;
    RECT r;
    HDC drawDC;
    HBITMAP prevbitmap;

    r.left = 0;
    r.top = 0;
    r.right = width;
    r.bottom = height;
    ZeroMemory(&bi, sizeof (BITMAPINFO));
    bi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof (BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.bmiHeader.biWidth = (LONG) width;
    bi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -((LONG) height);           // negative height to force top-down drawing;
    bi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = (DWORD) (width * height * 4);
    bitmap = CreateDIBSection(NULL, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &ppvBits, 0, 0);
    if (bitmap == NULL)
        panic("error creating HBITMAP for unscaled ImageList image copy");

    drawDC = CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
    if (drawDC == NULL)
        panic("error getting DC for checkbox image list bitmap");
    prevbitmap = SelectObject(drawDC, bitmap);
    if (prevbitmap == NULL)
        panic("error selecting checkbox image list bitmap into DC");
    (*drawfunc)(drawDC, &r, cbState, theme);
    if (SelectObject(drawDC, prevbitmap) != bitmap)
        panic("error selecting previous bitmap into checkbox image's DC");
    if (DeleteDC(drawDC) == 0)
        panic("error deleting checkbox image's DC");

    return bitmap;
}

static HIMAGELIST newCheckboxImageList(HWND hwnddc, void (*sizefunc)(HDC, int *, int *, HTHEME), void (*drawfunc)(HDC, RECT *, int, HTHEME), HTHEME theme)
{
    int width, height;
    int cbState;
    HDC dc;
    HIMAGELIST il;

    dc = GetDC(hwnddc);
    if (dc == NULL)
        panic("error getting DC for making the checkbox image list");
    (*sizefunc)(dc, &width, &height, theme);
    il = ImageList_Create(width, height, ILC_COLOR32, 20, 20);      // should be reasonable
    if (il == NULL)
        panic("error creating checkbox image list");
    for (cbState = 0; cbState < checkboxnStates; cbState++) {
        HBITMAP bitmap;

        bitmap = makeCheckboxImageListEntry(dc, width, height, cbState, drawfunc, theme);
        if (ImageList_Add(il, bitmap, NULL) == -1)
            panic("error adding checkbox image to image list");
        if (DeleteObject(bitmap) == 0)
            panic("error deleting checkbox bitmap");
    }
    if (ReleaseDC(hwnddc, dc) == 0)
        panic("error deleting checkbox image list DC");
    return il;
}

HIMAGELIST makeCheckboxImageList(HWND hwnddc, HTHEME *theme)
{
    if (*theme != NULL) {
        HRESULT res;

        res = CloseThemeData(*theme);
        if (res != S_OK)
            panic("error closing theme; HRESULT: %x", res);
        *theme = NULL;
    }
    // ignore error; if it can't be done, we can fall back to DrawFrameControl()
    if (*theme == NULL)     // try to open the theme
        *theme = OpenThemeData(hwnddc, L"button");
    if (*theme != NULL)     // use the theme
        return newCheckboxImageList(hwnddc, themeSize, themeImage, *theme);
    panic("error loading theme");
    return NULL;        // unreached
}
```

Comment: Could this be related? From MSDN: A memory DC exists only in memory. When the memory DC is created, its display surface is exactly one monochrome pixel wide and one monochrome pixel high. Before an application can use a memory DC for drawing operations, it must select a bitmap of the correct width and height into the DC. To select a bitmap into a DC, use the CreateCompatibleBitmap function, specifying the height, width, and color organization required.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would affect things, but I can tell you [from experience](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033636/winapi-gdi-fillrectcolor-btnface-fills-with-strange-grid-like-brush-on-window) that just results in a black and white bitmap. Unless you're suggesting the monochrome bitmap is being blitted on top, in which case why does this not affect all images?